# How to list the files in a directory for a program who creates a .tar file with the directory?

Tags: c, tar

How could I list the files in a directory after doing a `chdir()` to do a `stat()` on the files contained by the directory?

```
chdir(av[i]);
/* list the file */
stat(file1);
```

Comment: found it, it was the readdir function.

Comment: man opendir() and readdir().

Comment: start by looking at [`opendir`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/opendir.html) then ask a more specific question